# Meaning of 'subject + to + infinitive'?

Tags: sentence-construction, headlinese

Every now and then I find some articles' titles built up like this:
"Trump to meet with game industry over gun violence next week"

Well, I don't know how to find more information about this. I understood what the title says but I haven't managed to get the rule to build a sentence in this way. Can you explain me further?

Comment: This construction is not a sentence. It's an abbreviation of "Trump is to meet ..." -- it's employed only in situations like headlines and captions, to save space.

Comment: Look up **headlinese**.  We get many questions here about the way that headlines are written.

Comment: The comments are fine, except when using the copula it's not a journalistic shortcut: "The Pope is to be anointed this Friday" (meaning the Pope *will* be anointed this Friday), "This passage is to be understood as a condemnation of illiteracy" (meaning the passage is intended to be a condemnation of illiteracy), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Titles, especially in journalism, aim to immediately draw in readers.
Journalists have to be quick and efficient.

Instead of saying "Trump plans to meet with the game industry in order to discuss gun violence next week," journalists try to stick to a condensed version of the sentence, one that still makes sense and gets the point across.

From a grammatical point of view, please consider this definition provided by Google:

> ["to" may be used] in various phrases indicating how something is related to something else (often followed by a noun without a determiner).
>   "made to order"

Compared to other languages, such as French, English is rather lenient in many respects. As you can see above, this is a similar situation to the Trump example.

The best reasoning for this is the attention-grabbing nature of journalism.